# Swift updating UITableView in the background

Tags: ios, multithreading, uitableview, swift, asynchronous

I'm trying to update my UITableView in the background. While my current code is working I'm having 2 major errors with it.

In more detail. I'm using coreData to fill the cells. But I also have 2 API's I need to connect to.

Currently. I have 2 functions:

`loadSuggestions()` and `updateSuggestions()`

`loadSuggestions` fills gets the correct information and it displays fine.

`updateSuggestions` deletes all the current data, fetches the new data, saves it into CoreData, and reloads the `UITableView`. (this function is run as the last thing in my `loadSuggestions()` function, in the background)

So my major problem. Is when I load the suggestions. If I try to interact with the UITableView before it's done updating I get the error: `fatal error: Array index out of range` The reason is simple. I'm deleting the CoreData in the beginning of my function. During this period, it expects my array to be 0, but scrolling down obviously tries to load data outside the array index.

However I have no idea how to fix the above problem.

My second lesser important issue lies in /performance/? After the updateSuggestions() is done running. It doesn't actually update my `UITableView` with the changed data until several seconds later, or if I interact with the `UITableView`. It should of course, update the moment it's done updating?

I have no clue on how to fix either of the 2 problems. hence why I'm here.

Here's my code for the 2 functions:

loadSuggestions()

```
func loadSuggestions() {

    println("----- Loading Data -----")
    // Set the managedContext again.
    managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!

    // Check what API to get the data from
    if Formula == 0 {
        formulaEntity = "TrialFormulaStock"
        println("Setting Entity: \(formulaEntity)")
        formulaAPI = NSURL(string: "http://api.com/json/entry_weekly.json")
    } else if Formula == 1 {
        formulaEntity = "ProFormulaStock"
        println("Setting Entity: \(formulaEntity)")
        formulaAPI = NSURL(string: "http://api.com/json/entry_weekly.json")
    } else if Formula == 2 {
        formulaEntity = "PremiumFormulaStock"
        formulaAPI = NSURL(string: "http://api.com/json/proff_weekly.json")
        println("Setting Entity: \(formulaEntity)")
    } else if Formula == 3 {
        formulaEntity = "PlatinumFormulaStock"
        println("Setting Entity: \(formulaEntity)")
        formulaAPI = NSURL(string: "http://api.com/json/fund_weekly.json")
    }

    // Delete all the current objects in the dataset
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: formulaEntity)
    let a = managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil) as! [NSManagedObject]
    stocks.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
    for mo in a {
        stocks.append(mo)
    }
    // Removing them from the array

    // Saving the now empty context.
    managedContext.save(nil)

    // Reload the tableview with the new data.
    self.tableView.reloadData()
    self.view.hideLoading()
    self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(Int(QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED.value), 0)) {
        self.updateSuggestions()
    }

}
```

and updateSuggestions:

```
func updateSuggestions() {
    println("Updating Suggestions")
    if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork() == false {
        println("ERROR: -> No Internet Connection <-")
    } else {
        // Delete all the current objects in the dataset
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: formulaEntity)
        let a = managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil) as! [NSManagedObject]
        for mo in a {
            managedContext.deleteObject(mo)
        }
        // Removing them from the array
        stocks.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
        // Saving the now empty context.
        managedContext.save(nil)

        // Set up a fetch request for the API data
        let entity =  NSEntityDescription.entityForName(formulaEntity, inManagedObjectContext:managedContext)
        var request = NSURLRequest(URL: formulaAPI!)
        var data = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: nil, error: nil)
        var formula = JSON(data: data!)

        // Loop through the api data.
        for (index: String, actionable: JSON) in formula["actionable"] {

            // Save the data into temporary variables
            stockName = actionable["name"].stringValue
            ticker = actionable["ticker"].stringValue
            action = actionable["action"].stringValue
            suggestedPrice = actionable["suggested_price"].floatValue
            weight = actionable["percentage_weight"].floatValue

            // Set up CoreData for inserting a new object.
            let stock = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!,insertIntoManagedObjectContext:managedContext)

            // Save the temporary variables into coreData
            stock.setValue(stockName, forKey: "name")
            stock.setValue(ticker, forKey: "ticker")
            stock.setValue(action, forKey: "action")
            stock.setValue(suggestedPrice, forKey: "suggestedPrice")
            stock.setValue(weight, forKey: "weight")

            // Get ready for second API call.
            var quoteAPI = NSURL(string: "http://dev.markitondemand.com/Api/v2/Quote/json?symbol=\(ticker)")

            // Second API fetch.
            var quoteRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: quoteAPI!)
            var quoteData = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(quoteRequest, returningResponse: nil, error: nil)
            if quoteData != nil {
                // Save the data from second API call to temporary variables
                var quote = JSON(data: quoteData!)
                betterStockName = quote["Name"].stringValue
                lastPrice = quote["LastPrice"].floatValue

                println("Updated lastPrice for \(betterStockName)")

                // The second API call doesn't always find something, so checking if it exists is important.
                if betterStockName != "" {
                    stock.setValue(betterStockName, forKey: "name")
                }

                // This can simply be set, because it will be 0 if not found.
                stock.setValue(lastPrice, forKey: "lastPrice")

            } else {
                println("ERROR ----------------- NO DATA for \(ticker) --------------")
            }

            // Error handling
            var error: NSError?
            if !managedContext.save(&error) {
                println("Could not save \(error), \(error?.userInfo)")
            }
            // Append the object to the array. Which fills the UITableView
            stocks.append(stock)
        }

        self.tableView.reloadData()
        println("Finished Updating Suggestions")
    }
}
```

The reason I'm running updateSuggestions() in the background, is because it takes a very long time for it, to make all the API calls. And the user needs to be able to interact and see the current data while that is loading.

/Possibly/ unrelated, I'm also receiving some memory warnings.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think your second problem is caused by calling reloadData from a background thread. Are you not using an NSFetchedResultsController?

Comment: for the first problem. keep the data until you have finished updating data. then replace the old with the new data.

Comment: @rdelmar You're right. Moving it to the main Thread fixed the loading time! Thanks you once again.

Comment: @Volker I understand the logic behind that. What I don't know, is how to do it. Because I'm looping through, each API call. I'm saving the data as it goes. How can I get all of this data, save it. Then delete only the old data afterwards?